# HTTPS iframe shows as HTTP (mixed content)

Tags: html, http, iframe, https

I've an iframe with a HTTPS URL which shows up as HTTP. I can't seem to figure out why it shows my HTTPS link as HTTP and therefore throwing a mixed content error. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/"},atok:"648d22a7cbd8d39ff6c1d603172e4867",petok:"c4b2f316536247173a516f5b497b137d814de31b-1441717697-86400",betok:"907c8bfe67d347db6e2954b8e5aae965c633df1e-1441717697-120",zone:"addmilk.nl",rocket:"0",apps:{"ga_key":{"ua":"UA-64317812-1","ga_bs":"2"}}}];!function(a,b){a=document.createElement("script"),b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],a.async=!0,a.src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=e9627cd26a/cloudflare.min.js",b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}()}}catch(e){};
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-64317812-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

(function(b){(function(a){"__CF"in b&&"DJS"in b.__CF?b.__CF.DJS.push(a):"addEventListener"in b?b.addEventListener("load",a,!1):b.attachEvent("onload",a)})(function(){"FB"in b&&"Event"in FB&&"subscribe"in FB.Event&&(FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create",function(a){_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","like",a])}),FB.Event.subscribe("edge.remove",function(a){_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","unlike",a])}),FB.Event.subscribe("message.send",function(a){_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","send",a])}));"twttr"in b&&"events"in twttr&&"bind"in twttr.events&&twttr.events.bind("tweet",function(a){if(a){var b;if(a.target&&a.target.nodeName=="IFRAME")a:{if(a=a.target.src){a=a.split("#")[0].match(/[^?=&]+=([^&]*)?/g);b=0;for(var c;c=a[b];++b)if(c.indexOf("url")===0){b=unescape(c.split("=")[1]);break a}}b=void 0}_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","twitter","tweet",b])}})})})(window);
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://cdn.addmilk.nl/track?id=1&amp;preview_id=150908_thuiscomfort_tell_badkamer_728x90&amp;preview_name=Thuiscomfort%20-%20Tell%20-%20Badkamer%20-%20728x90" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error when loading the page even though my src URL is loaded over HTTPS:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://demo.addmilk.nl/test.html' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   'http://cdn.addmilk.nl/track/?id=1&preview_id=150908_thuiscomfort_tell_badkamer_728x90&preview_name=Thuiscomfort%20-%20Tell%20-%20Badkamer%20-%20728x90'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Must be your cache, it shows fine for me (besides a 404, but it's https so I think it's fine)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what kind of questions can be asked here. Yours is off topic since it does not involve any code

Comment: Also happens on every other computer or address I test it on.

Comment: @apachenick, did you ever figure out what caused this?

Comment: Ever found the root cause? I am experiencing the same problem on https://ha-mim.org/kayitlar

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042344/iframe-blocked-as-insecure-content-even-though-the-iframe-is-https/48068394#48068394, this did the trick for me. Not exactly sure the root cause... If anyone knows I'll gladly update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Look into the dev tool console of your browser. In the network tab you should see request and the protocol used (http or https).

Maybe cdn.addmilk.nl redirect to http ?